# wordpress $wpdb->prefix not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I've been given the code below by the Relevanssi support guys but I need to adjust this for a multisite setup.

The first block of code is the original of what I was sent which im assured works and the second is how I've tried to convert for multisite use.

The problem is I cannot get either to work! both result in the index skipping all posts but I need to check that I have got the query right for a multisite setup as im not too familiar with these queries...

```
add_filter( 'relevanssi_indexing_restriction', 'rlv_hidden_cats' );
function rlv_hidden_cats( $restriction ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $restriction .= " AND post.ID NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr, $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.parent NOT IN (13, 14, 15)) ";
    return $restriction;
}
```

......

```
add_filter( 'relevanssi_indexing_restriction', 'rlv_hidden_cats' );
function rlv_hidden_cats( $restriction ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $restriction .= " AND post.ID NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM $wpdb->prefix->term_relationships AS tr, $wpdb->prefix->term_taxonomy AS tt WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.parent NOT IN (13)) ";
    return $restriction;
}
```

my changes take place on the "$restriction" line

Comment: Please use $wpdb->yourtablename not prefiex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multisite, if it's not a root website, you can get prefix with  `$wpdb->get_blog_prefix($blog_id)`

Then, you can do

```
$base_prefix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix($123);
$restriction .= " AND post.ID NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM {$base_prefix}term_relationships AS tr, {$base_prefix}term_taxonomy AS tt WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.parent NOT IN (13, 14, 15)) ";
```

If it's a root website, you can use `$wpdb->base_prefix`.

```
$restriction .= " AND post.ID NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}term_relationships AS tr, {$wpdb->base_prefix}term_taxonomy AS tt WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.parent NOT IN (13, 14, 15)) ";
```

If it's a current website in multisite:

```
$restriction .= " AND post.ID NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships AS tr, {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy AS tt WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.parent NOT IN (13, 14, 15)) ";
```

P.S. `$wpdb->prefix` and `$wpdb->base_prefix` are **strings**, you can't do `$wpdb->prefix->term_relationships`. You can however do something like `$wpdb->term_relationships` which will give you full name of the table term_relationships (for example, if prefix is wp_, you'd get wp_term_relationships)